# Powershell Conditional based on Robocopy results

Tags: powershell, robocopy

Essentially I have a file that is copied from one folder to another only if the modified date is different (if the file is newer).

Is it possible to create a conditional based on the results of robocopy, If the file is copied do one thing, if no files is copied do something else?

**This is the robocopy statement I am running in Powershell currently:**

```
robocopy "C:\Folder1" "C:\Folder2" *.* /xo
```

Comment: Of course that's possible. robocopy returns an [exit code](https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy-exit.html) you could test for. ;-) Or, if it's only one file you could use Powershell without robocopy.

Answer (score 0):

```
robocopy "E:\Temp\dir1" "E:\Temp\dir2" *.* /xo

if ( $LASTEXITCODE -eq 1) {
    Write-Host "Success!"
}
else {
    Write-Host "Something happened !"
}
```

This would be the code I use. Still learning. You can expand this code with switch and case statements. Look for the Exit codes in the documentation of robocopy here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy
Sorry. The german documentation.

Comment: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy)